# libav seeking to n seconds in a video and saving frames there onwards

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg, libav, seek

I've been trying to seek in a mpegts video file. After exploring many codes, I've come up to the following stage of fetching frames and saving them.
However after using av_seek_frame also I'm getting following results:

1. Initial 7-8 frames are saved as grey frames.
2. Thereafter frames are fetched from beginning of the video only. i.e. 0 seconds onwards, while I'm trying to seek from say 12th seconds onwards.

Can you please explain how should I be calculating the timestamp and do the things correctly?

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

  int stream_id;
  int64_t timestamp;
  char ts_buf[60];


  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("You need to specify a media file.\n");
    return -1;
  }
  
  logging("initializing all the containers, codecs and protocols.");

 
  AVFormatContext *pFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();
  if (!pFormatContext) {
    logging("ERROR could not allocate memory for Format Context");
    return -1;
  }

  logging("opening the input file (%s) and loading format (container) header", argv[1]);
  
  if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatContext, argv[1], NULL, NULL) != 0) {
    logging("ERROR could not open the file");
    return -1;
  }

  logging("format %s, duration %lld us, bit_rate %lld", pFormatContext->iformat->name, pFormatContext->duration, pFormatContext->bit_rate);

  logging("finding stream info from format");
  
  if (avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatContext,  NULL) < 0) {
    logging("ERROR could not get the stream info");
    return -1;
  }

  AVCodec *pCodec = NULL;
  AVCodecParameters *pCodecParameters =  NULL;
  int video_stream_index = -1;

  // loop though all the streams and print its main information
  for (int i = 0; i < pFormatContext->nb_streams; i++)
  {
    AVCodecParameters *pLocalCodecParameters =  NULL;
    pLocalCodecParameters = pFormatContext->streams[i]->codecpar;
    logging("AVStream->time_base before open coded %d/%d", pFormatContext->streams[i]->time_base.num, pFormatContext->streams[i]->time_base.den);
    logging("AVStream->r_frame_rate before open coded %d/%d", pFormatContext->streams[i]->r_frame_rate.num, pFormatContext->streams[i]->r_frame_rate.den);
    logging("AVStream->start_time %" PRId64, pFormatContext->streams[i]->start_time);
    logging("AVStream->duration %" PRId64, pFormatContext->streams[i]->duration);

    logging("finding the proper decoder (CODEC)");

    AVCodec *pLocalCodec = NULL;

    pLocalCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(pLocalCodecParameters->codec_id);

    if (pLocalCodec==NULL) {
      logging("ERROR unsupported codec!");
      // In this example if the codec is not found we just skip it
      continue;
    }

    // when the stream is a video we store its index, codec parameters and codec
    if (pLocalCodecParameters->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
      if (video_stream_index == -1) {
        video_stream_index = i;
        pCodec = pLocalCodec;
        pCodecParameters = pLocalCodecParameters;
      }

      logging("Video Codec: resolution %d x %d", pLocalCodecParameters->width, pLocalCodecParameters->height);
    } else if (pLocalCodecParameters->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
      logging("Audio Codec: %d channels, sample rate %d", pLocalCodecParameters->channels, pLocalCodecParameters->sample_rate);
    }

    // print its name, id and bitrate
    logging("\tCodec %s ID %d bit_rate %lld", pLocalCodec->name, pLocalCodec->id, pLocalCodecParameters->bit_rate);
  }

  if (video_stream_index == -1) {
    logging("File %s does not contain a video stream!", argv[1]);
    return -1;
  }

  AVCodecContext *pCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(pCodec);
  if (!pCodecContext)
  {
    logging("failed to allocated memory for AVCodecContext");
    return -1;
  }

  if (avcodec_parameters_to_context(pCodecContext, pCodecParameters) < 0)
  {
    logging("failed to copy codec params to codec context");
    return -1;
  }

  if (avcodec_open2(pCodecContext, pCodec, NULL) < 0)
  {
    logging("failed to open codec through avcodec_open2");
    return -1;
  }

  AVFrame *pFrame = av_frame_alloc();
  if (!pFrame)
  {
    logging("failed to allocate memory for AVFrame");
    return -1;
  }

  AVPacket *pPacket = av_packet_alloc();
  if (!pPacket)
  {
    logging("failed to allocate memory for AVPacket");
    return -1;
  }

  /*seek for 20 seconds*/
  int64_t incr, pos = 5;

  int64_t seek_target = (pos * AV_TIME_BASE), stream_index = 0, how_many_packets_to_process = 50, response = 0;

  printf("seek_target before : %lu\n", seek_target);
  seek_target = av_rescale_q(seek_target, AV_TIME_BASE_Q, pFormatContext->streams[stream_index]->time_base);

  printf("seek_target after: %lu\n", seek_target);

  do
  {
    response = decode_packet(pFormatContext, pPacket, pCodecContext, pFrame, seek_target);
    if (response < 0)
      break;
    avcodec_flush_buffers(pCodecContext);

    /*av_frame_unref(pFrame);
    av_packet_unref(pPacket);*/
    // stop it, otherwise we'll be saving hundreds of frames
    if (--how_many_packets_to_process <= 0) 
      break;

  }while(1);

logging("releasing all the resources");

  avformat_close_input(&pFormatContext);
  av_packet_free(&pPacket);
  av_frame_free(&pFrame);
  avcodec_free_context(&pCodecContext);
  return 0;
}


int decode_packet(AVFormatContext *pFormatContext, AVPacket *pPacket, AVCodecContext *pCodecContext, AVFrame *pFrame, int64_t seek_target)
{
  if(av_seek_frame(pFormatContext, 0, /*(startTime + frameTimestamp) / 10*/seek_target, AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD) < 0)
  {
    printf("error while seeking\n"/*, pFormatContext->filename*/);
    return -1;
  }
  avcodec_flush_buffers(pCodecContext);

  while(1)
  {
    if(av_read_frame(pFormatContext, pPacket) < 0)
    {
      logging("av_read_frame failure");
      break;
    }

    /* I'm not able to get to correct timestamp to discard prior frames upto desired seconds. This if hasn't worked out well as of now. */
    if((av_q2d(pFormatContext->streams[0]->time_base) * pPacket->pts) < (seek_target * 1000))
    {
      printf("skipping the frame\npFormatContext->streams[0]->time_base: %d %d\tpckt.pts: %lu\tseek: %lu", pFormatContext->streams[0]->time_base.num, pFormatContext->streams[0]->time_base.den, pPacket->pts, seek_target);
      av_packet_unref(pPacket);
      continue;
    }

    // Send Packet for decoding
    int response = avcodec_send_packet(pCodecContext, pPacket);

    if (response < 0) {
      logging("Error while sending a packet to the decoder: %s", av_err2str(response));
      return response;
    }

    while (response >= 0)
    {
      response = avcodec_receive_frame(pCodecContext, pFrame);
      if (response == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || response == AVERROR_EOF) {
        break;
      } else if (response < 0) {
        logging("Error while receiving a frame from the decoder: %s", av_err2str(response));
        return response;
      }

      if (response >= 0) {
        logging(
            "Frame %d (type=%c, size=%d bytes, format=%d) pts %d key_frame %d [DTS %d]: %d",
            pCodecContext->frame_number,
            av_get_picture_type_char(pFrame->pict_type),
            pFrame->pkt_size,
            pFrame->format,
            pFrame->pts,
            pFrame->key_frame,
            pFrame->coded_picture_number,
            pPacket->dts
        );

  char frame_filename[1024];
        snprintf(frame_filename, sizeof(frame_filename), "%s-%d.pgm", "im/frame", pCodecContext->frame_number);

        if (pFrame->format != AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P)
        {
          logging("Warning: the generated file may not be a grayscale image, but could e.g. be just the R component if the video format is RGB");
        }
        // save a grayscale frame into a .pgm file
        save_gray_frame(pFrame->data[0], pFrame->linesize[0], pFrame->width, pFrame->height, frame_filename);

        av_frame_unref(m_pAVFrame);
        
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: According to [this post](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=libav-user@ffmpeg.org&q=subject:%22%5C%5BLibav%5C-user%5C%5D+Why+does+av_seek_frame%5C%28%5C%29+not+seek+to+a+keyframe%5C%3F%22&o=newest&f=1), and [this post](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/403721-Wrong-duration-of-TS-file), seeking an MPEG-TS file is problematic. For correctly decoding a video stream, we must start at a key frame, but MPEG-TS has an issue that it is not seeking to a key frame (I can't say for sure if this is the issue in your case).

Comment: It is evident in my case that it isn't able to find the keyframe that is closer to seeking point. But also it is not even checking from the desired seeking point. after av_seek_frame(), it is traversing through 0th frame itself.
@Rotem you mean this code should work out perfectly for other formats like mp4? or anything else is required to change?

Comment: I think the part when you *"get to correct timestamp to discard prior frames up to desired seconds"* is incorrect. As I understand it, we can't just ignore the packed: `av_packet_unref(pPacket);`. We have to decode all the packets up to the correct frame (decode and then ignore), because after each key frame, there is a "frame dependency chain" up to the next key frames (there are P-frames and B-frames...).